# Mongolite substring query

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

In my collection I want to filter out all documents having a title that starts with "Once". Implementing this query in MongoDB Compass works fine

```
query = '{"title" : /^((?!Once).)/i }'
```

but trying to do the same in R with mongolite returns the error:

> Invalid JSON object.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in Mongolite you can avoid that error using MongoDB's [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) with `"` instead of `\` :

```
query = '{"title": {"$regex": "^((?!Once).)" , "$options": "i"}}'
```